# MC Attributes in Salesforce Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, campaign, distributed-marketing

I'm working on Distributed Marketing (DM).

I have created an Email Template in MC and configured with Salesforce Campaign for sending Email from Salesforce Org to the Leads/Contacts.

I have added the First Name as personalization in Email Template, so it should work in both MC & Salesforce Org.

I'm facing some issues while using First Name attribute in the Email template.

When I'm using %%First Name%%, it's not fetching the first name for both MC & Salesforce Org.

So, I referred to the Data Extension (DE) which I have created for Journey dedicated to DM Email Sending.
In that DE, First Name attribute was firstName. After using this attributed in Email Template, the Email preview in Salesforce is not generated.

I just want to know, can we use MC attributes in Salesforce Org for Personalization? If yes, then how?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Generally if there is any scripting in your email, in salesforce preview of that email will not be generated, Because ampscript is for MC and salesforce CRM doesnt support it. It will not be able to read the email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable first then call it inline.

```
%%[ set @firstName = firstName ]%%

Hello %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```